# Connecting SSIS WebService task to Spring WevService

Tags: ssis, wireshark, spring-ws

I have a SSIS package in which i use a WebService task to call a Spring WS.
The authentication is done by client certificate and username & password.

I have tried to do it like this a simple HttpConnection and a WebService task - Error 504 Gateway Timeout. When i edit the HttpConnection and click on Test Connection i get an error that states:
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

I have tried doing it with a script task and the same error.
I have even tried with a dummy console application and the same result.

I also have a java written app that actually does the job but i do not have access to it's code-behind. This basically proves that the problem is not from the server itself.
The java application has it's own keystore and the same certificates that i have installed on the server.

I opened a wireshark capture and i saw that when i used either of my apps the host made a DNS request for an address that i did not configure anywhere(it seems like a proxy address from the intranet), while the java app made a DNS request with the correct address.

I am stuck here, and i have no idea what the problem might be or what else i can do so that i would get a proper error.

Please advise!

Edit:

This is the code that calls the WS:

```
public static void CallWebService()
        {
            var _url = "https://<IP>/App/soap/DataService";
            string action = "getData";
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters.Add("param1", "0");
            parameters.Add("param2", "0");
            parameters.Add("param3", "value");

            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(action, parameters);
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url);
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

            // begin async call to web request.
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

            // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
            // do something usefull here like update your UI.
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            // get the response from the completed web request.
            string soapResult;

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            string thumbprint = "CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT";
            byte[] thumbprintArray = new byte[thumbprint.Split(new char[]{ ' ' }).Length];
            string[] stringArray = thumbprint.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            for (int i = 0; i < thumbprintArray.Length; i++)
            {
                thumbprintArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(stringArray[i], 16);
            }

            X509Store localStore = new X509Store("My");
            localStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCol = localStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);

            foreach (X509Certificate cert in certCol)
            {
                if (cert.GetCertHashString() == thumbprint)
                {
                    webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                    break;
                }
            }

            webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD");

            return webRequest;
        }

        private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string action, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            string formatedParameters = string.Empty;
            string paramFormat = "<{0}>{1}</{0}>";

            foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
            {
                formatedParameters += string.Format(paramFormat, key, parameters[key]);
            }

            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(string.Format(@"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://custom/soap/"" xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soap:{0}>
            {1}
        </soap:{0}>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>", action, formatedParameters));
            return soapEnvelop;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are correct, the problem is not the server but in your code. That's not an insult, simply a statement. Decompose your problem into one that is less complex. For now, eliminate SSIS from the equation. Get your dummy console app working as the steps it takes to resolve that will be directly applicable to making it work within SSIS. Have you tried pointing a decompiler at the .class files to understand the steps the java app takes?

Comment: Also, we are not mind readers so posting of the invocation code will make it easier for us to provide feedback as to what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: The issue could be in the host file or however your DNS is being resolved. Pls. check with your network admin.

Comment: The problem with the DNS i solved... by default if you do not specify the Proxy, HttpWebRequest goes and gets the default proxy set-up on the machine, so for this i set the Proxy to null. Now the only problem remains "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel". The cerificate seems to be okay, the chain of trust is okay, just a warning inside the certificate for the Basic Constraints property.

Comment: I took a closer look at the certificate and i realized it was signed for a wildcard domain, as i used the IP... the problem was here... differences between the request and the certificate. And now a new error occurs: The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. This i believe is out of my reach given that the WebService is black boxed.